# Child processes not dying with kill(pid_t, SIGTERM)

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I am coding in C and attempting to fork a server that accepts connections from clients to its own process, however, the server persists to accept connection on the port specified after I use a command line argument to terminate it.

```
pid_t server_id;

 int spawn(char* func, char** argl)
{
    pid_t cid;
    cid = fork();
    server_id = cid;
    if(cid!=0)
        return cid;
    else
    {
        execvp(func, argl);
        int errcode = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reached: %s\n",strerror(errcode));
        abort();
    }

}
```

...

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //stuff

    do{
        next_option = getopt_long (argc, argv, short_options,long_options, NULL);
        switch (next_option)
        {
            case 'h':   /* -h or --help */
                print_usage (stdout, 0);

            case 's':  ; /* -s or --start-server */
                char* arglist[] = {"server",argv[2],NULL}; //argv[2] is the port number
                spawn(server_path,arglist);
                break;

            case 'x':   /* -t or  --transport */
                kill(server_id,SIGTERM);
                printf("SERVER TERMINATED\n");
                break;

        //more stuff

    return 0;
}
```

server.c is a multithreaded server that can accept connections from multiple clients. I did not include the code for it, since I believe when terminating a process its threads are killed with it?

Comment: What's `server_id`?

Comment: `server_id` is just a `pid_t` integer variable that is the value of cid, or the child process id.

Comment: Did it print "SERVER TERMINATED" ? The server_id is child process pid indeed, could you rewrite SIGTERM signal handler in your server_path server binary?

Comment: what happens if you manually `kill -TERM <your server pid>` from the terminal ? does this terminates your server ? before issuing the `kill()` you might want to add a debug statement `fprintf(stderr, "TERMINATING server %d\n", server_id);` to make sure you are killing the right process

Comment: What this prints is `TERMINATING server 0`, for some reason the return from `fork()` is always 0

Comment: I figured out why it is happening but do not know how to fix it. I am executing the server with command line argument in the main program. The server is made to a process and then the main function terminates, so when I present the argument `-x` to terminate the server it has no reference to the previous execution.

Comment: And, what happened to argv[0] and argv[1]?

Answer (score 0):

Because the child pid is not persistent in the parent function and the child happens to be a server that listens to a port, I am doing

```
strcpy(command,"lsof -t -i:"); //get pid of process listening to port number
strcat(command,argv[2]); //concatenate port
in = popen(command,"r");
fgets(temp,5,in); //save output from running command
printf("%s\n",temp);
server_id = atoi(temp);
fprintf(stderr, "TERMINATING server %d\n", server_id);
kill(server_id,SIGTERM);
printf("SERVER TERMINATED\n");
```